# Выбрать рандомное значение. Vk api. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Сама часть кода:

```
if "/выбери" in event.text:
    if event.from_chat:
        str = event.text
        array = str.split("или")
        A1 = [1,2]
        vk.messages.send(
            chat_id=event.chat_id,
            random_id=get_random_id(),
            message=array[random.choice(A1)],
            reply_to=event.message_id
        )
```

Но когда вводится команда /выбери да или нет, он вводит только нет, а значение да просто не прописывает, без ошибки. Выбор разных разделителей не помог. Был бы рад помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
A1 = [0,1]
```

Индексация строк начинается с нуля: у первого символа индекс 0, следующего 1 и так далее.

если я правильно понял что требуется:

```
import re

if "/выбери" in event.text:
    if event.from_chat:
        str = event.text
        array = str.split("или")
        array[0] = re.findall(r'(\S+)[\s]+$', array[0])[0] # уберет /выбери
        array[1] = array[1].strip() # уберет пробел после 'или'
        A1 = [0,1]
        vk.messages.send(
            chat_id=event.chat_id,
            random_id=get_random_id(),
            message=array[random.choice(A1)],
            reply_to=event.message_id
        )
```

Comment: Ныне, он отправляет сообщения следующего типа:
при команде /выбери 1 или 2, он выводит 
2
или
/выбери 1, после чего один раз повторяет команду.

Comment: вы можете уточнить что хотите сделать?

Comment: Благодарствую за дополнение, помогло!